# Laravel andWhere does not exists

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my query;

```
SELECT * FROM digital_cases WHERE name LIKE $request->name . '%' 
AND added_by IN (SELECT id FROM assistants WHERE firstname LIKE $request->addedBy . '%');
```

And i tried this :

```
$digital_cases = DB::table('digital_cases');

if ($request->has('caseName')) {
    $digital_cases = $digital_cases->where('name', 'LIKE', $request->caseName . '%');
    if ($request->has('addedBy')) {
        $addedBy = $request->addedBy;
        $digital_cases = $digital_cases->andWhere('added_by', 'IN', function ($digital_cases) use ($addedBy) {
            DB::table('assistants')->select('id')->whereIn('firstname', 'LIKE', $addedBy . '%');
        });
    }
}


$digital_cases = $digital_cases->get();
```

I deleted before question is wrong but now everything seems ok. But i got an error :

> Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::andWhere does not exist.

Comment: Yes actually `andWhere does not exist.`

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: laravel 5.6    null null null.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `where()`.

By default, Laravel will assume you want to do `AND WHERE`. It's when you want to use `OR` that you have to be specific i.e. `orWhere()`.

Comment: I think i ve second mistake about "in", should i use whereIn instead of where ?

Comment: @Nevermore https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-wherein-and-wherenotin-with-subquery-example-using-query-builderexample.html